# cancelAllLocalNotifications on Apple Watch

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, localnotification

I'm having trouble to remove all the local notifications using a UIButton on the Apple Watch. In the iPhone app everything works fine, but when I use the same code for the Apple Watch it won't work.

This is the code I use for the Apple Watch:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotification];
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the "s" on "cancelAllLocalNotification".

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not call UIApplication on the WatchKit extension because is not part of WatchKit framework.

Give a look at : [WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:)

That will allow you to communicate with the AppDelegate of your main app like this you can call your method.